# Variable fuera de foreach JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var res = '';
resultados.forEach(async (resultado) => {
    const url = resultado.entry_url;
    const respuesta = await fetch(url);
    const resultadoInner = await respuesta.json();
    res = res + resultadoInner.sequence + '\n';      
});
console.log('resultado:' + res);
```

No muestra el `console log` de la variable res ¿qué estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: Tu función es asíncrona, tienes que esperar a que termine. Aún no se le asigna el valor a `res` cuando lo imprimes.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, ahora la pregunta es cómo me cercioro que terminó?

Answer (score 5):

Ampliando la información de Alberto Rojas...

En JavaScript cuando se ejecuta una función asincrona no es posible volver al sincronismo inicial. Aunque ahora exista el concepto asinc await, esto no es mas que una herramienta que utilizan los compiladores del navegador donde por debajo utilizan promesas y a su vez callbacks asincronos.

Es por eso que cuando te dice Alberto Rojas que tienes que "esperar a que termine para imprimir" es por que javascript aunque le dices que espere **javascript no espera**.

Mi consejo a esto que estas haciendo utiliza un promise.all para acumularlo todo:

```
var res = "";
var procesoRes = async function (resultado) {
 const url = resultado.entry_url;
 const respuesta = await fetch(url);
 const resultadoInner = await respuesta.json();
 res = res + resultadoInner.sequence + '\n';
 return res;
};

Promise.all(resultados.map((resultado) => { return procesoRes(resultado) }))
 .then((resArr) => {
     //por aquí llega todos las iteracciones
     console.log("Acaba de acabar");
     console.log(res);
 });
```

Mi consejo es que aprendas a usar promesas antes de usar async/await... Por que por debajo son promesas y usar algo sin conocimiento previo.... es jodido.

Un Saludo!

Comment: me lanza que resultado.entry_url es undifined, problema del .map?

Comment: Si perdón te arreglo esto es que no se pasa el argumento al procesoRes

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes una cantidad de promesas que tienes que esperar es conveniente usar `Promise.all()`, recibe como argumento un array de promesas, en tu código sería algo como esto:

```js
var res = [];
const promesas = [1,2,3].map(async (resultado) => {

  const respuesta = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const resultadoInner = await respuesta.json();
  
  res.push(resultadoInner);
  
  return res;
  
});

Promise.all(promesas).then(c=>console.log(c));
```

Obviamente modifiqué `res` y otras cosas para que el ejemplo funcione realmente con un ajax. El array `[1,2,3]` representaría `resultados` en tu código.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tienes un lista de funciones asíncronas que no han terminado su ejecución cuando llegas a la línea de `console.log`. Tienes que esperar a que todo termine, por ejemplo con algo así:

```js
//simulamos la llamada a fetch con esta función
async function mockFetch(url) {
   return new Promise(function(completar) {
      setTimeout(()=> completar(`Completada ${url}`),100);
   });
}

const resultados = [ 'http://Url1', 'http://Url2', 'http://Url3' ]

//obtenemos un array de promesas
let promesas = resultados.map(async (resultado) => mockFetch(resultado));



Promise.all(promesas).then(resultados => {
  let resultadoFinal = resultados.join('\n');
  console.log(resultadoFinal);
});
```

Comment: cómo capturo el resultado de fetch, el campo resultado.entry_url arroja la url a consultar. El console.log muestra, por ejemplo: Completada omabrowser.org/api/protein/10406574, pero lo que quiero capturar es el resultado separado por \n de ese fetch

Comment: por alguna razon la funcion mockFetch no está arrojando el resultado deseado, una url de entrada podria ser https://omabrowser.org/api/protein/10406574/

Comment: Esa función simplemente simula un fetch (no hace la llamada AJAX)

Comment: @PabloLozano Usar setTimeout() es mejor forma de simular un proceso asíncrono, pero nadie lo entiende :(